# Sequence - the same date in following years

Tags: f#, sequence

I want to create a sequence which returns as a result all years when day of the week is the same as in function parameter
(for example: all  years when 12nd February is Sunday, since start date).

```
let myDate (dw:System.DayOfWeek) (start:System.DateTime) =
    seq {
            ...
        }
```

Hope you understood what I mean.

Comment: We do understand what you mean, but what have you tried and what do you find tricky about it? This is not a code writing service...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
let myDate (dw:System.DayOfWeek) (start:System.DateTime) =
    Seq.initInfinite ((+)1) // from 1..∞
    |> Seq.map start.AddYears
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x < DateTime.MaxValue)
    |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.DayOfWeek = dw)
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Year)

myDate System.DayOfWeek.Monday (new DateTime(2001,1,1)) |> Dump
```

or

```
let myDate (dw:System.DayOfWeek) (start:System.DateTime) =
    let rec inner i =
        seq {
            let someDay = start.AddYears(i)
            if someDay.DayOfWeek = dw then yield someDay.Year
            yield! inner (i+1)
        }
    inner 1

myDate System.DayOfWeek.Monday (new DateTime(2001,12,1)) |> Dump
```

Comment: `(id >> (+)1)` is a funny way of saying `((+)1)`. ;-]

Comment: Oh yeah, I blame it on lack of coffee :-D

Comment: Note that leap years are a corner case you're going to have to deal with. Calling `AddYears(6)` on Feb 29th, 2012 (a Wednesday) is going to yield Feb 28th, 2018 (which will also be a Wednesday). So you'll get false positives with this approach unless you also check that the calendar date was unchanged by the `AddYears(i)` call. See the [`AddYears` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx) for details on how it handles Feb. 29th.

Comment: You are right, I'll come back to this later and fix the leap year issue

Answer (score 1):

Stuart's answer is fine, but I can't help but think "eh, I'd delete some of that code." You know, start with an unterminated sequence of years with that particular month/day and let the caller determine how many to take or add a filter of their own.

You should be thinking "fool's errand" at this point. **:)** The first problem I ran into--because my second feeble test failed--was that you can't merrily go on incrementing a `DateTime` forever, so you have to write code to limit that.

So I ended up with rather more code than less, due to dealing with the vagaries of real data:

```
// All instances of this specified month/day beginning with 'start'.
let myDate (dw:System.DayOfWeek) (start:System.DateTime) =
    // Start with a sequence of one date for each year...
    seq {
        // Don't run the date past DateTime.MaxValue, there lurks an
        // ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Comparison also must be on the
        // valid side of DateTime.MaxValue. Don't bother with try/with
        // here in a sequence expression, you can't do that.
        let maxDateBarrier = DateTime.MaxValue.AddYears(-1)
        let mutable keepGoing, date = true, start

        while keepGoing do
            yield date

            // if date.Year % 100 = 0 then printfn "%A" date.Year

            if date <= maxDateBarrier then
                date <- date.AddYears(1)
            else
                keepGoing <- false
    }
    |> Seq.where (fun date -> date.DayOfWeek = dw)
```

A bit wordy. Test #1 works fine:

```
let printDates (dates : DateTime seq) =
    for date in dates do
        printfn "%A" date.Year

// Take the next 5
myDate DayOfWeek.Sunday DateTime.Now
    |> Seq.take 5
    |> printDates
```

Test #2 actually iterates through *all* of the dates in my sequence:

```
// Take up to 5 before 2040.
// Note: this statement actually iterates through *all* the years in the
// sequence if you truncate to a length longer than Seq.where returns.
myDate DayOfWeek.Sunday (DateTime(2017, 2, 13))
    |> Seq.where (fun date -> date.Year < 2040)
    |> Seq.truncate 5
    |> printDates
```

Is Test #2 a reason to add an `endDate` to the `myDate` function? No, it's more an argument to use sequences better. Use `takeWhile` instead of `where`:

```
// Try again: Take up to 5 before 2040.
// Terminate the sequence early with takeWhile.
myDate DayOfWeek.Sunday (DateTime(2017, 2, 13))
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun date -> date.Year < 2040)
    |> Seq.truncate 5
    |> printDates
```

Much better. Missed my goal of "less code," but I'm okay with that. **:)**

Comment: This is *more* code (not that less code should be the goal), and adds mutability. But it's always nice to see other answers =)

Comment: I'd say that "less code" should *often* be the goal, because that usually aids readability. (Of course, that doesn't apply if the shorter code is a Perl-one-liner-like mess.) Antoine de Saint-Exupéry once said, "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away," and he was entirely right. Usually, when you pare your design (or your code) down to its essentials, the result is more elegant and easier to read. Thus, I usually strive for "less code" as a rule-of-thumb design goal.

Comment: @Stuart yeah, I thought I made it pretty clear that I "missed my goal of 'less code.'" :) What was interesting to me was the boundary cases that came up, unterminated sequences that terminate, and misuse of sequence operations. Mind you, I'm not serious enough about it to deal with leap years, it was some lunchtime musing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm too lazy to code this, but I would go about it this way to find an effective and fast algorithm that takes leap years into account. It's an interesting task I think, and it would be interesting to compare the speed with other answers.

There's 14 possible calendars. How these calendars repeats is something you can find out quickly if you google it. I found this.

"The Gregorian calendar repeats itself in 28-year cycles. A calendar for a particular non-leap year repeats itself after 11 years twice and repeats itself after six years once in a 28-year span. Calendars for leap years repeat themselves every 28 years."

How a particular day in the year repeats, I guess can be slightly more complicated, but if so then not by much.

Any one of the seven non-leap calendars will of course match with one of the leap year calendars from Jan to Feb, except Feb 29 of course. It seems obvious at first thought that there will also be a match from March on, except it will be skewed by one day and one calendar compared to Jan..Feb28. Needs checking. I am wondering whether this will affect an algorithm, and if so, how.

If your input is 29th Feb, then obviously only leap years need be considered.

From this it should be quite simple to write an algorithm.

Hope this makes sense somehow. I am not sure what happens each 400 years, or if something else can go wrong. But it is easy enough to run through all reasonable dates to test, and adjust if needed.